# Reset coupon usage limit after a specified time in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scheduled-tasks, coupon

So basically in WooCommerce, I would like to reset coupon 'usage_limit' and 'usage_limit_per_user', after an hour of interval periodically. But, I'm unable to do that.

I tried the following:

```
add_action( 'save_post', $this,'reset_usage_limit' );
function reset_usage_limit() {
  add_action( 'init', 'custom_delete_coupon_meta_function' );

  wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 60, 'init', array( $coupon_id ) );

}

function custom_delete_coupon_meta_function( $coupon_id ) {
  delete_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'usage_limit' );
  delete_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'usage_limit_per_user' );
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Here, just to test if it is working or not, I have set the schedule time to 60 seconds.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing that in the right way:

- You need to replace `'init'` hook by a custom named hook for the scheduled event triggered by `wp_schedule_single_event()` function at the specified time.
- Related `add_action()` is always outside the function using `wp_schedule_single_event()`.
- You need also to check if any coupon usage limits is active, before.
- Don't use `save_post` hook as it is a generic hook used by all WordPress post types and also it is triggered before coupon data is updated. 
  Always try to use dedicated WooCommerce hooks instead.
- Always try to use [`WC_Coupon` getter and setter methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-coupon.php) (or [`WC_Data` methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php)) instead of WordPress `get_post_meta()`, `add_post_meta()`, `update_post_meta()` or `delete_post_meta()` generic functions.

Try the following *(untested)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'trigger_coupon_schedule_single_event', 10, 2 );
function trigger_coupon_schedule_single_event( $post_id, $coupon ) {
    // Check that some usage limit has been activated for the current coupon
    if ( $coupon->get_usage_limit() || $coupon->get_usage_limit_per_user() ) {
        // Create a shedule event on 'coupon_schedule_reset_restrictions' custom hook
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 60, 'coupon_schedule_reset_restrictions', array( $coupon ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'coupon_schedule_reset_restrictions', 'coupon_reset_restrictions' );
function coupon_reset_restrictions( $coupon ){
    $coupon->set_usage_limit(null);
    $coupon->set_usage_limit_per_user(null);
    $coupon->save();
}
```

It should work.

Now, you should know that WordPress scheduled task are not very reliable.

You should consider using [Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/) plugin instead, as it is a scalable and traceable job queue for background processing.

Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included and used by WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions.
The documentation is available on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/)

Comment: That was really helpful, appreciate that.

Comment: Hello Brother
Sorry to disturb you again. I just wanted to know that is the ActionScheduler is independent of any page load? I want to run the cron job regardless of any user visits to the site. Will it be achievable via ActionScheduler?
Thanks in advance

Comment: ActionScheduler is dependent of the WordPress activity/processes, but I think that ActionScheduler uses HeartBeat API (a simple server polling API built in to WordPress, allowing near-real-time frontend updates), so it shouldn't be a problem.